# Edge based platonic solid origami

Tags: origami

A while ago I made a few origami platonic solids based on this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TV7sbaffuNo

I managed to find a way to modify the module to work for other platonic solids and not just the dodecahedron. Unfortunately, I have since lost the method to do that.

Does anyone know how to modify the folding of the M-shape to work for creating triangles and squares rather than pentagons?